# Change default Rest Position from Object mode

Tags: animation

Im trying to change my characters default Rest Position. What I want to do is change it in the Object Mode and make it the default Rest Position. But every I export it or go into Edit mode the model "returns" to the orginal Rest Position.

Also the character have an animation on it (if that is to any use) and it is imported from Mixamo.

What I want
[image]

It returns to its default Rest Position when I export it or click on Edit mode
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this way:

- First, close any action in the *Dope Sheet*
- Give your armature the pose you want to be the rest pose, in *Pose* mode, select the body, duplicate the *Armature* modifier, disable the first one, apply the second one:

[image]

- Reactivate the first *Armature* modifier, don't pay attention to the weird character pose, select the armature, in *Pose* mode go into *Pose > Apply > Apply Pose as Rest Pose*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it kind of worked but the animation is broken after that

Comment: Yes if you change the rest pose the animations won't work as they used to, because the bones have been rotated but the actions keep the same rotation value